# Translating JavaScript array into array insertion to Java

Tags: javascript, java

I have this in Javascript:

```
var population = [];
for(i=0; i < size; i++){
    population[i] = functionWhichReturnsArrays();
}
```

A single dimensional array containing multiple arrays in different indices - this is what I want and not a 2D array.

How can I translate this to Java?

Comment: You don't (with arrays). Javascript has dynamic arrays. Java does not.

Comment: What's another way to do this in Java?

Comment: `Object[] population = new Object[size];` to create the array, then a `for` loop similar to the JS one to populate it.

Comment: Where is the distinction between an array of arrays and a 2D-Array?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you an idea on how to approach it in Java (the code can be written a lot fancier but this is easy to follow):

```
public class Pop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Pop().build(10);
}

private void build(int size) {
    String[][] population = new String[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        population[i] = functionWhichReturnsArrays();
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < population.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < population[a].length; b++) {
            System.out.print(population[a][b] + " / ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private String[] functionWhichReturnsArrays() {
    String[] strs = new String[2];
    strs[0] = "zero";
    strs[1] = "one";
    return strs;
}

}
```

Result will be 10 rows:

```
zero / one / 
zero / one / 
...
zero / one /
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Use an ArrayList.

**Answer**

Java offers lots of data structures to choose from with the built in `Collections`.
The decision which one to use is highly dependent on the nature of the specific use case.
Usually it's a tradeoff between flexibillity and performance.

From the sparse description you provided I assume that your
requirements to the data structure are more or less the following

- Don't know or care about the number of elements
- A data structure that keeps the order of the elements
- A need to access the elements by an index

While the latter two are fullfilled by a Java array the first one is not since arrays have a fixed size.
Unless there are more specific requirements I'd suggest to use an `ArrayList`.

As an example I create lists of random Numbers and random length in `somethingThatReturnsAList()`.
Of cause you can use other value-types than Numbers here.
Also, it should be possible to use completely different value-types for each list entry.

The list of lists, that you asked for is created in the `main` method at the end.

`printThat()` just prints contents of the number-lists for each index of the list
of lists with the help of a StringBuilder.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListTest {

  public static List<Number> somethingThatReturnsAList() {
    int          count;
    int          value;
    List<Number> result;

    // Random number of elements.
    count  = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    result = new ArrayList<Number>(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      // Random value.
      value = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
      result.add(value);
    }

    return result;
  }

  public static void printThat(List<List<Number>> listOfLists) {
    StringBuilder bldr;
    List<Number>  subList;

    bldr = new StringBuilder();

    bldr.append("The contents:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.size(); ++i) {

      // Top list index.
      bldr.append(i).append(": ");
      subList = listOfLists.get(i);

      // List sub list values.
      for (int j = 0; j < subList.size(); ++j) {
        if (j > 0) {
          bldr.append(", ");
        }
        bldr.append(subList.get(j));
      }

      System.out.println(bldr.toString());

      bldr.setLength(0);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int                 size;
    List                subList;
    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists;

    size        = 5;

    // Create that list of lists
    listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      subList = somethingThatReturnsAList();
      listOfLists.add(subList);
    }

    // Print that list of lists
    printThat(listOfLists);
  }
}
```

This prints something like:

```
The contents:
0: 5, 1, 2
1: 
2: 4, 2, 9, 3, 0, 7, 6
3: 0, 1, 5, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 5
4: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// var population = [];
ArrayList<TYPE_RETURNED_FROM_FUNTION> population = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // adds at the end of the array Liste; wich is i
    population.add(functionWhichReturnsArrays());
}
```

Comment: I believe `TYPE_RETURNED_FROM_FUNTION` must be an array / list so you can be more specific here.